# Decoding bytes received in a socket with Python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, decode

I'm using a LabVIEW simulator that I have connected to via the `Python3 socket` Library

```
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip=socket.gethostbyname("127.0.0.1")
port=1234
address=(ip,port)
client.connect(address)
while True:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    print(data)
    client.close()
```

The output of data is:

> b'&&\r\n0108500.00\r\n01410.000000\r\n01420.000000\r\n01430.000000\r\n01440.000000\r\n01450.000000\r\n0146200.000000\r\n0147100.000000\r\n!!\r\n&&\r\n0108500.00\r\n01410.000000\r\n01420.000000\r\n01430.000000\r\n01440.000000\r\n01450.000000\r\n0146200.000000\r\n0147100.000000\r\n!!\r\n'

The simulator is outputting two constant values of `200` and `100` which I correspond to `\r\n0146200.000000\r\n0147100.000000\` `0146 and 0147` are tag ID's from the simulator.  Whats the best way to parse this data (Lets assume for this question I only want the tagID and Value of the last two)? I've tried to output it with:

```
print(data.decode("utf-8", "strict"))
```

output:

> &&
>   0108500.00
>   01410.000000
>   01420.000000
>   01430.000000
>   01440.000000
>   01450.000000
>   0146200.000000
>   0147100.000000 !! &&
>   0108500.00
>   01410.000000
>   01420.000000
>   01430.000000
>   01440.000000
>   01450.000000
>   0146200.000000
>   0147100.000000 !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to extract the keys and values:

```
import re

results = [
    dict(re.findall(r"(\d{4})([\d.]+)", string))
    for string in filter(
        bool,  # non-empty
        data.decode("utf8", "replace").split("&&"),
    )
]
```

Results for your data:

```
[{'0108': '500.00',
  '0141': '0.000000',
  '0142': '0.000000',
  '0143': '0.000000',
  '0144': '0.000000',
  '0145': '0.000000',
  '0146': '200.000000',
  '0147': '100.000000'},
 {'0108': '500.00',
  '0141': '0.000000',
  '0142': '0.000000',
  '0143': '0.000000',
  '0144': '0.000000',
  '0145': '0.000000',
  '0146': '200.000000',
  '0147': '100.000000'}]
```